# Can the C compiler optimize a conditional store into an unconditional store?

Tags: c, optimization, language-lawyer

Take the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool global;

bool foo(void) {
    if (global) {
        global = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this code theoretically equal to the following?

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool global;

bool baz(void) {
    bool tmp = global;
    global = false;
    return tmp;
}
```

I am inclined to think that `foo` and `baz` are theoretically equivalent: `global` is not volatile and there is nothing else forcing the compiler to consider multithreading (something like `atomic_bool`, for example). So I would think that if a branch is way more expensive than a store, then the compiler would opt to go with the `baz` solution instead of the `foo` one. But I cannot get the compiler to actually do this, taking the GCC 13.2.0 RISC-V compiler with `-std=gnu2x -march=rv32if -mabi=ilp32f -O3 -mbranch-cost=2000` still results in `foo`. On the other hand, I am also unable to make the compiler turn `baz` into `foo`.

So am I wrong and is there a theoretical difference between `foo` and `baz`? Or is this just an optimization GCC (RISC-V?) does not take?

Comment: No, those two functions are not equivalent. In the first the assignment to `global` is conditional, in the second it's unconditional. The compiler can (and likely will) generate different code for them, even when building with optimizations enabled.

Comment: But a compiler is allowed to turn conditional code into unconditional code when there are no measurable side effects, right? The easy example of this would be something like `static const bool f = false; if (f) printf("true); else printf("false");`, which gets turned into `printf("false")` every time.

Comment: Yes, but then the compiler already knows the state of `f`. When your `foo` or `baz` function is called, the state of `global` is unknown. There's no way for the compiler to deduce the value of `global`.

Comment: But it does not have to deduce `global`, right? If `global` was already `false`, then writing `false` to it does not have measurable side effects. If it was `true`, then it needs to become `false`, so a write is forced. Therefore, writing `false` in all scenarios has the exact same side effects as only writing `false` when global was `true`.

Comment: Some compilers today will generate a conditional move so that even though there is formally an if statement in the HLL code the machine code execution path is not branched (evidently not on GCC RISC-V though).  The second form you show will always assign false to the global every time  that it executes.  Even so I expect the second form is still slightly faster. I'd expect both to inline at higher optimisation levels.

Comment: You're assuming removing the branch is an optimization.

Comment: @Barmar: No, they are not assuming it; the question explicitly states it as a condition: “… if a branch is way more expensive than a store, then…”

Comment: @Barmar It might be. Many embedded systems have memory with single cycle access, but a conditional branch might still induce bubbles in the pipeline. So there are real world scenarios where doing an unconditional write is cheaper than a branch.

Comment: @Cheiron I'm not asserting that it isn't. But I generally assume that the compiler writers know what the proper optimizations are, so if they're not doing this optimization it may not actually be optimal.

Comment: Removing the branch would force a cache line to become dirty, wouldn't it?

Comment: @IanAbbott Is the C spec concerned with this? You might be right on some platforms, but some caches are inteligent enough to not mark a line as dirty when there are no actual changes, and some processors do not have caches at all. So generally I would not think that compilers have to take this into account.

Comment: @Cheiron No, the C spec is not concerned with cache lines, but it might be a "quality of implementation" issue in the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The two functions differ in a multithreaded environment. Consider what happens if there is a thread that reads `global` from time to time and `foo` or `baz` is called while `global` contains `false`. In this situation, `foo` will not store to `global` but `baz` will.

C 2018 5.1.2.4 4 defines *conflict*:

> Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

C 2018 51.2.4 35 says:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

This means the behavior with `baz` is undefined, since the modification to `global` (Note 2 in C 2018 3.1 3 tells us “‘Modify’ includes the case where the new value being stored is the same as the previous value.”) in the thread calling `baz` conflicts with the read in the other thread.

However, the behavior with `foo` remains defined in this situation, as it does not modify `global`. (Since the behavior of `baz` is undefined, the compiler could generate the same code for it that it does for `foo`.)

Note this difference in the semantics of the routines does not preclude the compiler from generating the same code for them. In a single thread, the two routines have the same semantics as defined by the C standard:

- There is no observable behavior inside either routine (no access to volatile objects, no data written to files, no input/output interactions).
- After either routine is called, `global` contains `false` and the return value is `true`.
- Neither routine makes any other changes to program state.

Therefore, regardless of which routine is called, the single-thread effects on observable behavior and abstract machine state are identical.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you stating that a function like `baz` will always be considered undefined behaviour if you use `-std=c18` or higher?

Comment: @Cheiron: No. I cited C 2018 because it is the current C standard, not because its specifications around multithreading differ from earlier or (expected) later versions. Nor does `baz` necessarily have undefined behavior. As I wrote, it has different semantics from `foo`. Whether the program it is in has defined behavior or undefined behavior is a function of both `baz` and other things in the program, not `baz` alone.

Comment: Would you say it counts as a modification, for the purposes of the language spec, to store the same value in an object that that object already contains?  This answer suggests so, but I'm not finding that expressed explicitly in the spec.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: This answer quotes Note 2 in C 2018 3.1 3: “‘Modify’ includes the case where the new value being stored is the same as the previous value.” 3.1 defines “access” as “to read or modify the value of an object”, and Note 2 says that “Modify” includes storing the value it already has.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying an object is what C formally calls a *side effect* (c17 5.1.2.3), and compilers aren't allowed to optimize out "needed side effects", but "needed" is quite subjective...

The C standard doesn't really say anything about if compilers are allowed to add new side effects not present in the original code. It just says that the compiler is not allowed to affect the outcome of the program - the "observable behavior". Accessing a `volatile` object affects the observable behavior, but that does not apply here.

Replacing the former function with the latter is a manual optimization that at least the programmer can do. I'm not sure why neither gcc nor clang optimizes the code to remove the branch, but we tend to over-estimate optimizers at times - they don't work by magic.

However, if you change the code to

```
global = false;
global = false;
```

Then only one side effect is "needed" and one can be removed, since the object is not `volatile` and writes to plain variables have no special meaning other than being side effects. The extra write here does get optimized out.

Note that the compiler likely has no clue how the external linkage variable `global` may be used elsewhere in the program, which might limit possible optimizations.

Comment: "Note that the compiler likely has no clue how the external linkage variable global may be used elsewhere in the program, which might limit possible optimizations." Does it, though? There is the general assumption that the program is single-threaded and the memory does not change without direct interference from the code (you can break both of these assumptions by using atomics or `volatile`, but neither are used here). This assumption is exactly why writing multithreaded code or using interrupts is a bit of a minefield.

Comment: @Cheiron Threading isn't why. It simply can't assume that external functions called from within the same translation unit as itself do not modify the variable. This in turn restricts optimizations such as inlining + re-ordering. The variable will have to be reloaded from RAM each time the function is called etc etc.